# xamarin forms group listview checkboxs

Tags: forms, listview, xamarin

Checkboxs are generated in the Listview. The status of the checkbox need to stored in the  local storage. Is there any way to bind two separate list into one Listview.

First List:

```
    List<mergedfeature> mergedfeatures = new List<mergedfeature>();
    
               
                    var res = (from layer in layers
                                     join cat in category
                                     on layer.feature_cat equals cat.id
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         name = cat.category_name,
                                         Mfeatures = layer,
                                         isChecked = true
                                     }).ToList();

Second List:

     public int id { get; set; }
     public string layer_name { get; set; }
     public bool LayerChecked { get; set;}
     public string group_name { get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to bind two separate list into one Listview.

Is the second list nested inside the first list? If yes, you can use [BindableLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts) to display a collection of items in another Listview.

You can bind the inner list in `BindableLayout.ItemsSource`.

You can refer to the following code in my demo:

```
    <ListView  x:Name="lstView" RowHeight="60">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Olive">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text = "{Binding Name}" FontSize="24" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.25, 0.25, 400, 40"/>
                            <Label Text = "{Binding Type}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="50, 35, 200, 25"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalOptions="End" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="250.25, 0.25, 50, 50 "/>

                        <StackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Inner_Items}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                                        <Label Text="{Binding layer_name}"/>

                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding LayerChecked}"/>

                                    </StackLayout>
                                    
                                    
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Second list is not nested.

Comment: need to join IEnumerable<Grouping<string,mergedfeatures>> with ObservableCollection<checkedlayer>

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow you. Can you explain that in detail?